# How to use embedded device as bluetooth HSP/HFP source

Tags: embedded, bluez

I have ARM based board, kernel 4.14.67 and bluez-4.101. I want to connect bluetooth headset for playing sound from the board. My question is similar to that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36295784/bluez-4-101-on-embedded-arm-device
I try to do the following:

1) make a file named `.asoundrc` in home directory

2) `hciconfig hci0 up piscan`

3) `bluetoothd -d -n` (how to make debug output more verbose?? It prints just a small amount of info)

4) `sdptool add hs` - Is this enables Headset profile?

5) power on headset and enter pairable mode on it

6) `hcitool cc 00:1C:EF:9F:86:BC` - try to connect to headset, there is no any output from the command and I don't know is it successful or not?

7) then I immediately call `hcitool con` and see

```
Connections:
        < ACL 00:1C:EF:9F:86:BC handle 43 state 1 lm MASTER
```

but a few seconds later subsequent call of `hcitool con` returns nothing connected.

No debug output in dmesg or from bluetoothd seen. What may be the reason of connection goes down?

8) Try to play `aplay -D btheadset ./testsound.wav`, but it failed:

```
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
aplay: main:722: audio open error: Connection refused
```

`.asoundrc` contents:

```
pcm.btheadset {
    type plug
    slave {
        pcm {
            type bluetooth
            device "00:1C:EF:9F:86:BC"
            profile "auto"
        }
    }
    hint {
        show on
        description "Bluetooth Headset"
    }
}
ctl.btheadset {
    type bluetooth
}
```